# Solids of Revolution about Y axis. I keep getting a negative volume?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals, volume

Question: . The solid obtained by revolving about the y-axis the region enclosed by the curves x = y^2 and x = y + 2

Where I get to:
[image: o]

What am I doing wrong? If for A(y) is change the order of radius subtraction I get a positive but I am sure that approach is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: You are integrating between the wrong values of $y$. Use the $y$ values of the two points of intersection of the two curves.

Comment: I see, would that be between -1 and 2 on the Y axis?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2=y+2$ gives $y=-1$ or $y=2$.

Thus, the volume it's
$$\pi\int\limits_{-1}^2((y+2)^2-(y^2)^2)dy=...$$
I got $14.4\pi.$